# "List up to three", so I can put in only two?

Tags: grammar

It says:

> Please list up to three projects (in order of preference) you are
>   interested in.

So I am not sure: Do I have to put in exactly three projects or can I also just put in two?

Comment: You can put in two; as a dictionary will tell you, *[up to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20to)* indicates a bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put in three or fewer projects, since up to is a limiting factor, but does not require a minimum, so by this grammar, two projects would be an acceptable response.

Comment: As would 1 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can put two.

You can put one, two, or three.